# Javascript import/export dependencies

Tags: javascript, import, module, leaflet, export

Here's the cutdown code of the problem.

### library.js

```
export var a = ...
export var b = ...
export var c = ... result of call to leaflet API
```

### main1.js

```
<script src='leaflet.js'></script>
<script type="module"></script>
import {a,b,c} from "../library.js"
.. use a,b,c successfully
...
</script>
```

### main2.js

```
<script type="module">
import {a,b} from "../library.js"
... loading fails because L (from leaflet.js) not defined
...
</script>
```

main1.js executes correctly. Imported variables a, b and c have expected values.

main2.js will not run. I don't need or import c, so do I not include the leaflet API. Yet, loading still tries to resolve c, can't, and fails.

Why is c being examined when not specifically requested?

What's the pure javascript workaround/solution?
(I've tried importing L from leaflet.js in main2.js but without success)

Research suggests that a NodeJS or CommonJS environment provides a solution, but I want a pure module/import/export solution.

Comment: So the question here would be how are you importing/loading the Leaflet code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what happens when you import something -

1. Import {a, b} from './library.js'
2. Go and find 'library.js' in current directory
3. **Execute all of the code in 'library.js'**
4. Only if you do step 3., will the compiler know what is being returned and exposed from 'library.js'
5. Although there is a concept of tree-shaking which removes useless exports to decrease your bundle size, which works on static imports.
6. To verify for yourself add some 'console logs' in 'library.js' and you can see those are executed anytime you import 'library.js'
7. Hence, when 'library.js' is executed, it also needs to evaluate and assign value to var c, and hence is executing the leaflet API

Solutions I can think of -

1. Let var c, be the function, which calls the leaflet API, rather than function call.
2. Separate a,b in one file and c in another file.

Ref -

1. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-javascript/tree-shaking
2. https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_benefit-dead-code-elimination-during-bundling
3. https://javascript.info/import-export

Comment: Tree shaking indeed works on static import, but the point which makes it irrelevant to OP's case is that it is performed as part of a build step (comparable to development compilation), not when scripts are loaded as `type="module"`.

Comment: Cools got it.
I agree with you, I don't think there is any "build" step when directly injecting scripts using the <script> tag in HTML.
I only meant to mention tree-shaking here, as an idea one can explore upon.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response. I didn't know about 3. which was the source of my problem.
I thought about your solution 2. but I was centred on maintaining a single library/module.
I experimented with solution 1. I ended with testing whether the leaflet script had been loaded {var EXTENT = (typeof window.L != 'undefined') ? true:false;}. Then for the affected functions and vars ran a self-executing anonymous function which returned null if EXTENT was false or the (leaflet) result if true.
Thanks for the prompt. Problem resolved and a happy coder.

Comment: @Crow please make sure to _accept_ the answer that helped you. It also signals to others that your issue is solved.